# bash: using tr to create an array is not creating an array?

Tags: bash, tr

I'm modifying a script I found at https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-scripting-using-awk/ but stuck on why an array is not being created in the case below.  I looked up how to explode a string in bash and many sites say to use `tr` so I tried:

```
    FILES="$(ldd $pFILE | awk '{ print $1$2$3 }' | egrep -v ^'/')"

    for i in $FILES
    do
        arr=()
        arr=$(echo $i | tr '=>' ' ')
        
        echo "raw arr[0]=${arr[0]}"
        echo "raw arr[1]=${arr[1]}"
    done
```

All the results show that arr[1] is blank and arr[0] has the entire line except the **=>** was changed to **double space** (I though it should have changed it to a single space)

```
> raw arr[0]=libpthread.so.0  /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
> raw arr[1]=
```

Comment: That changes all = and > characters to space, so naturally => becomes double space - two replacements.

Comment: I thought it was converting one string to another string... I guess I need something else for that ?

Comment: tr translates individual characters to other characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the values inside `()` to create an array.

```
arr=($(echo "$i" | tr '=>' ' '))
```

There's no need for `arr=()` before that.